# thickbox not behaving like it should

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, thickbox

I'm creating a greasemonkey script. One of the functions it should do is close any thickboxes that open with the page (like when you visit sidereel for the first time). I put this line in

```
$('.ui-icon-closethick').click()
```

Yet it doesn't seem to do the trick. Am I missing something?

Comment: i am guessing the click event is fired before the thinkboxes is fully loaded or opened.

Comment: I tried setting a two second timeout with the same result

Comment: how are you calling the `click()` and also how are you loadign the thickboxes? ondomready or onload?

Comment: `setTimeout(function() { unsafeWindow.console.log($('.ui-icon-closethick').click()); }, 10000);` will show up on the console but not actually click away the thickbox. I'm using greasemonkey so all my code will fire after the page is loaded

Comment: I don't use sidereel and couldn't find an element with that class in a quick search of that site.  So, link to the target page and tell us what browser you are using Chrome, Firefox, or other?  The full code of your script would not be amiss, either.

Comment: This only works if you don't have any cookies already from the site, so open up private browsing or something [Here's the site](http://www.sidereel.com/Jersey_Shore/season-3/episode-11/search)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script is being executed after the popup is opened, so basically you can't prevent it from opening using Greasemonkey.

However, there is an addon called [**Mason**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/mason/) that will help you.
Just add the following rule:

**Description :** sidereel : Fake login
**Include URL :** ^http:\/\/www\.sidereel\.com\/
**Function :** Cookie Definition
**Config... :** seen_saved_source_popup=true

Leave the other fields blank.

If flashing the popup isn't the problem, then you may use the following:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           sidereel : hide welcome
// @namespace      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288097/
// @include        http://www.sidereel.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

if (unsafeWindow.$)
unsafeWindow.$("div[id *= 'lightbox-saved-source-']").dialog("close");
```

Comment: I thought your idea would be prevent it from opening, but if it isn't the problem... then it is possible

Comment: yeah I'm trying but for some reason it doesn't work. `setTimeout(function() { unsafeWindow.console.log($('.ui-icon-closethick').click); }, 10000);` will show the actual function yet when I try calling it that way it still doesn't work

Comment: Thats perfect, what exactly is it doing?

Comment: It is closing all dialogs that contain "lightbox-saved-source-" in its id attribute. If you want to be more specific, then you may change "div[id *= 'lightbox-saved-source-']" to "#anonymous-lightbox-saved-source-welcome" or whatever you prefer.